# Sequelize as a function in express JS always return isFulfilled and isRejected false

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

i have a helper like this

```
let connection     = require('./connection');
const Sequelize    = require('sequelize');
const sysUserModel = require("./models/sys_user");
const Sys_user     = sysUserModel(connection, Sequelize);
let queryUtils     = {
    getOldPassw: function (SYSUSER_ID) {
         return Sys_user.findOne(
             {
                 attributes: ['SYSUSER_PASSW'],
                 where     : {
                     SYSUSER_ID: SYSUSER_ID
                 }
             }
         ).then(function (row) {
            return row.dataValues.SYSUSER_PASSW;
    });
    }

};
exports.data       = queryUtils;
```

And this is my controller

```
let queryUtils     = require('../queryUtils');
let changePassword = function (req, res) {
    let oldPass       = queryUtils.data.getOldPassw('1010001');
    return res.send(oldPass);
};
module.exports = {
    changePassword
};
```

When i run my code, appears as below
[errorRestClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Igk.png)

And this is my console
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58NM9.png)

Would you like to help me to solve this case?
Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a promise from your `getOldPassw` function, so you need to operate on that. Currently, you're sending the promise to the client and not the value that the promise *resolves to*.

```
let changePassword = function (req, res) {
    queryUtils.data.getOldPassw('1010001')
        .then(oldPass => res.send(oldPass))
        .catch(err => {
            // Always good to handle errors!
            console.error(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
};
```

Comment: it works :D ,thank you for your help, I cannot pass all these troubles without your help